# pvz2 bugs in worlds?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

Right now I'm playing pvz2 and I beat the first 3 worlds but it it says that I haven't beaten them on the bottom of the world.For ancient Egypt it says that 21/25 levels beaten.For pirate seas 24/25 and for wild west 20/25. And when I open the worlds it shoes that I haven't beaten those levels and I have to do them again.HELP!!! Is this some sort of bug or do I have to do them again?

Answer (score 1):

I've been in a situation like this before.

It was iCloud doing this on my iPad.
Check for any cloud backup applications on your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you beat the Zomboss on all 3 worlds it sounds like a bug to me. Sorry.